# Path alias for `src` for Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack

I have a custom webpack configuration for Ionic 3 to use `src` as a path alias (i.e. to import from `src/module/file`):

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'src': path.resolve('./src')
  }
}
```

However, with Ionic app scripts @ 3, when I try to serve or build I get an error `Cannot find module src/module/file`.

I have seen ways to create path aliases to import from directories under `src` (such as `app`, `pages`, etc.) that involve updating the Webpack resolve alias as I have as well as updating baseUrl for `tsconfig.json`. For example:

https://medium.com/@siddhartha.ng/ionic-3-import-using-aliases-2aa260d6fab3

However, I want to be able to import from `src` rather than a subdirectory of `src`. Is there any way to do this by changing my webpack or TypeScript configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Per the updates to Ionic 3, webpack configuration now has two top-level properties, `dev` and `prop` for corresponding webpack configurations.

This means that you have to update the `dev` and `prod` properties and export the entire object from the webpack configuration. You can do this any way you like, but for example:

```
const config = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');

config[process.env.IONIC_ENV].resolve.alias = { src: path.resolve('./src') };

module.exports = config; // you can also export a function that returns this
```

Just keep in mind that you need to export the whole object with *both* configurations. `module.exports = config[env]` won't work.